# Calculating Year-To-Date Accuracy removing predicted forecasts

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet and looking to add what I think will be a simple formula.

The calculation I am looking for is to calculate the Actual Year-to-Date (YTD) percentage of delivery performance.

Currently the YTD calculation takes the sum of cells B13:G13 (Bulks Accurate) divided by the sum of cells B4:G4 (No of Bulks Due per week).  This doesn't show an accurate YTD as it also includes the forecasted number of bulks due in weeks 5 and 6.  I am looking for a formula that will include a statement to say if the yellow cells in row 6 are not completed then the YTD calculation will not include the forecasted bulks due in row 4.

Thanks for your help in advance!

[YTD Spreadsheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3SS5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you change the logic of row 11 (No of Bulks) to show the value in row 4, but only if row 6 AND 7 are blank? An `IF AND` formula would suffice, entered in `B11` and then copied across:

> =IF(AND(B6="",B7=""),0,B4)

Then, your YTD formula can be simply

> =SUM(B13:G13)/SUM(B11:G11)

This way, even if no delivery has taken place when due, you enter "0" and the % will then include that week's due figure in the overall calculation.

[1st Example Spreadsheet Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k83Kj.jpg)

If you can't change row 11 because it needs to match row 4, then you could insert a new row to implement the `IF AND` formula and amend my YTD formula above to use the new row instead of row 11.

If you can't add to the structure of your table at all, then you can still achieve the same result by using a `SUMIFS` as your divisor, as below:

> =SUM(B13:G13)/SUMIFS(B4:G4,B6:G6,">=0",B7:G7,">=0")

The only difference with the `SUMIFS` route, is both the row 6 and row 7 values must be set as at least 0 for it to include row 4's value. The first route means row 4's value is included as soon as row 6 OR row 7 have a value entered.

[2nd Example Spreadsheet Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2RfT.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! Your first example worked great! I was able to change row 11 and now my YTD works accurately!